# How To Search for multiple multi-word strings in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, regex, string

For example I'm trying to search for the occurence of both `hello world` and `goodbye world` in the same line. I've tried a bunch of difference iterations. For example, if you want to find one multi-word string you can throw it in brackets `/\<hello world\>` but I can't figure out how to have multiple check for multiple, multi word strings

I've tried

`/\<\(hello world \& goodbye world\)\>`

nor does this

`/\<hello world\>\&\<goodbye world\>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\&` atom does not do what you think it does. It allows to match two regular expression parts *at the same position*. To have both strings match in the same line, you need to allow for an arbitrary number of characters before the matches.

This is the pattern: `/.*red\&.*blue/`

For your example:

```
/.*\<hello world\>\&.*\<goodbye world\>/
```